# Hibernate with and without JNDI

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I'm using Hibernate 4 successfully with Tomcat 7. I now have a need to create a standalone application that also uses Hibernate, and will take advantage of the Hibernate code I'm using in my Tomcat app.

The Hibernate configuration currently uses JNDI with Tomcat.

Because of the code produced by the Hibernate auto-generation, it looks like it NEEDS JNDI to work (Here is a snippet of one of the XXXXHome classes :

```
protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("SessionFactory");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
    }
}
```

Anyone know how can I use these auto-generated Hibernate classes in a standalone environment?